# Why can't we measure a monochromatic wave's frequency perfectly over a finite range?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, wave-equation

In Fourier analysis it is said that the only way to have 0 uncertainty in a monochromatic wave's frequency is if you FT it over an infinite domain (otherwise it does not produce a delta function).

This makes sense to me as cosine (etc) waves with slight frequency differences can be negligibly different unless you compare them over many many cycles. However it seems to me they would still only be 'negligibly different' and not completely the same. In theory if we measured every point in a wave with 0 uncertainty, can't we just compare which single frequency passes through all of those points with absolutely 0 error to get the frequency perfectly without using an infinite domain?

Comment: You can have piecewise defined signals that match perfectly on an internal but vary wildly outside of that.

Comment: If you have additional conditions you can obviously reduce the sampling requirements. If you know your function is a pure sine wave with bounds on the frequency you only need 3 points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only examine a finite segment of your "apparently a monochromatic cosine", how do you know that it continues to be the same cosine outside that finite segment?  Only if you inspect the entire curve can you know that it really is the cosine that you inferred from the finite segment.

Are you familiar with [frequency modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation)?  This is a real practice, used for FM radio that produces a time varying frequency at fixed amplitude.  Just because an FM signal has a fixed frequency for a finite time interval does not mean it has that frequency for all times.

Now if, miraculously, you know you had a monochromatic cosine wave (i.e., you know something about the wave at all times outside your finite sampling window), then the noiseless wave data in your finite window are sufficient to determine exactly what frequency that wave has.  This **requires** knowing more than just what is in the window.

Comment: Thank you this does seem to make alot of sense. So would I be right in saying that the FT of a pure sine wave over a finite domain should be 0 nowhere because its possible that outside the finite domain the signal could be of any frequency (e.g. just constant)?

Comment: Also then is the reason why the FT tends to a delta function as you widen the domain because even if the signal is some completely different frequency outside of the domain, the amplitude of this frequency would necessarily have to be smaller since we know our original sine wave dominates for a larger region?

Comment: @AlexGower : To your first comment: It can be enlightening to do a noise analysis of a Fourier transform -- let the inputs be *intervals* of width, say, $1\%$ of the wave amplitude.  You end up with *huge* error bars in the FT, especially where the FT "should be" zero.  We usually ignore how unstable the FT results are to small changes **in** the sample window, and we're obviously ignoring our uncertainty about what's going on outside that window.

Comment: @AlexGower : To your second comment:  That's not wrong...  But it can be more enlightening to think of a sequence of successively more finely sampled discrete Fourier transforms converging to the continuous Fourier transform.  At each step, the finite transforms give convolutions with the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) (caused by the rectangular signal region that is represented by each sample value).  As the sampling refines, the sinc in the FT gets taller and narrower and goes to a delta in the continuous limit.

Comment: So does the finitely sampled discrete FT assume the function is zero outside the given finite range or?

Comment: @AlexGower : No.  The transform assumes the signal is periodic and that the sample window covers a whole number of periods.  For "fun", try running the transform on $\sin(x)$, but on $110\%$ of its period, from, say, $0$ to $\frac{11}{5} \pi$.  If you move the trailing end around, you can see all kinds of energy appear in the other bins caused by what the transform sees as a jump discontinuity where the signal leaves the windoe to the right and reappears on the left.

Comment: Okay thanks. The last thing that I think would help me is to fully understand what they mean when they say 'for longer finite intervals, the uncertainty in the frequency of the FT is reduced'. How exactly should I interpret the FT output as relating to the uncertainty. Surely the places fn where it is 0 are not ruling out those frequencies being needed if it turns out the signal is just fn for the rest of time outside the interval, and if we assume that the wave is monochromatic everywhere then even with a finite sample we would determine its frequency with 0 uncertainty.

Comment: @AlexGower : Another way to describe sampling a signal in a finite window (for the continuous transform) is to pretend that you multiply your signal (pointwise) with a rectangle that is $1$ in the window and $0$ outside the window.  As noted above, the FT of a rectangle is a sinc and the result of the FT of a pointwise product is the convolution of the two FTs.  So the finite window transform from an infinite sine wave gives a delta function "blurred" by a sinc.  The wider the window, the narrower the blurring, so the lesser the uncertainty in the frequency.

Comment: Oh okay so the 'uncertainty reduction' is purely in the sense that you know the FT has experienced less bluring from the sinc from the convolution theorem, it's nothing to do with the any frequencies in the FT being 'ruled out' and so being 0. Since we multiplied by that rectangle we assumed the signal was 0 outside our range which could be wrong so we can't read anything into certain frequencies of our FT being 0, all we know is that the 'actual' frequencies have been less distorted by the effect of this rectangle?

Comment: @AlexGower : You're mixing two ideas.  With prior knowledge that we have a finite window on a pure sine wave, the FT is the convolution of a sinc and a delta, a blurred version of the delta.  The frequency uncertainty is related to the width of the blurring.  A wider window gives narrower blurring gives less frequency uncertainty.  Without prior knowledge about the wave outside the window, the transform assumes periodicity -- this *ignores* the signal outside the window.  It produces "garbage" FTs if the window isn't an exact multiple of the period of the signal (if it has a period).

Comment: @AlexGower : You really might benefit from finding a way to automatically compute discrete Fourier transforms -- in a calculator, using software, or even in a spreadsheet.  Then play with varying the width of the sampling window (versus the period).